# Is it rude to take the lane, then filter when encountering congestion?

Tags: traffic, city, etiquette

In the city I live in, there's a lot of two lane roads.

I feel much more comfortable taking the lane, as to not have a car come up from behind and clip me while overtaking.

However, when I encounter congestion ahead, I can safely ride between cars, (because *I'm* the one judging the spacing).

This seems rude to be riding in a way that I'm not allowing people to overtake me (unless using a different lane to), but then allowing myself to overtake others. Are there any etiquette guidelines concerning this technique?

Comment: I'm used to that being described as "taking the lane" rather than "riding primary" (which I don't recall ever seeing before). It might be worth switching the term to the one more common in this site.

Comment: There is always a potential to be judged rude, especially by those who don't appreciate the complexities of cycling.  (And I've always seen it described as "claiming your lane".)

Comment: @Mσᶎ "Primary" and "Secondary" are terms of art from recent British cycling manuals and state sanctioned training. http://www.britishcycling.org.uk/cycletraining/article/ct20110110-cycletraining-Bitesize-Bikeability--Part-4--On-Road-Positioning-0

Comment: @SamuelRussell I can only guess that some bureaucrat felt that making up new terms would justify a hefty fee?

Comment: "Primary" and "Secondary" position are not new terms - they are used in John Franklin's book "Cyclecraft", first published over 20 years ago. Though the terms may now be becoming more well known with recent improvements in official training etc.

Comment: When passing traffic islands round here, taking the lane appears to be the only way to stop the cars squeezing through a gap that isn't wide enough to be safe, and sometimes is physically narrower than their car.  I've had many near misses and been hit once (when I was tucked in to the side of the road from making it easy to be passed on the preceding uphill and couldn't move out again before the island).

Comment: Keep in mind that it is not rude to inconvenience others for your safety, but it *is* rude to inconvenience others for your convenience.

Comment: What Daniel just said.

Comment: However, it should also be noted that there is a innate human (and chimp) perception of "fairness", and a perception of violating "fairness" rules can lead to vindictiveness on the part of the offended.

Answer (score 6):

In general, **yes it is rude**. But there can be times when it's acceptable.

I'm sure we all understand that you are trying to maximize your own safety. It is a tricky balance to achieve. *Especially since how you ride depends on the local driver and cyclist cultures, and local laws.*

In many places we cyclists struggle for respect and acceptance by the motoring majority. There are multiple overlapping factors / factions involved:

- The **might is right** faction. For whatever reason: permanent inferiority complex, transient anger, whatever. Logic will never prevail here, but **don't give them a reason to target you**.
- The **cyclists don't obey the rules** faction. Reinforced every time a driver sees a cyclist run a red light, ride on the footpath, or in many cases / places - split lanes, take up a whole lane, ride without a helmet, ride with no hands (on the handlebars), pop a mono, have fun, you name it. To them, if a cyclist does anything they as a driver can't do then it should be banned: the rules are **written and unwritten**.
- The **cyclists are unpredictable** faction. These people may appreciate that every cyclist is freeing up road space, but cyclists vary in experience and predictability. And in peak inner-city traffic it can be hard to know where we are: "Did I pass him yet? I can't see him; did he turn off? I don't want to hit him ...".

In summary: **obey the local rules**.

For example, I ride in 4 different conditions, when I'm **not in a bike lane or on a bike path:**

- Inner city, generally with heavy and congested (0-40kph) traffic. The drivers generally see lots of bikes, and have learned to accommodate. Because their max speed and mine match, I take a full lane when it's available. At lights, there are "bike boxes" painted on the road in front of the stopped traffic. Bikes are expected to start from there, so that they are visible to the traffic behind. So bikes often filter through the lanes when the traffic is stopped. This example **supports taking a lane**, but it is a limited case.
- Inner city, traffic dominated by recreational and fitness cyclists ([Kew Boulevard](https://www.google.com.au/maps/@-37.795034,145.018429,3a,75y,121.62h,75.91t/data=!3m4!1e1!3m2!1sj5jgpOhlWAa6aorjx3DwOw!2e0), for those who know it). The speed limit is 50kph, so on the downhills we usually take the whole lane. Elsewhere, we mostly use the bike lane, unless there is too much bike traffic to fit.
- Outer city (the 'burbs). While the traffic here has greatly improved in the last decade, taking a lane is putting your life in their hands. Some drivers are very bike aware, completely changing lanes to overtake. When other drivers see that behavior, they often copy it. But some drivers can look you in the eye and **just not see you**. Taking a lane is dangerous because to these drivers you simply don't exist. *It only takes one to take you out.*
- Outer city on regular cycling routes, with no bike lanes. If alone, I ride about a meter out from the curb, to avoid all the broken pavement and any rubbish. The local law says vehicles must drive "as near as practicable" to the side of the road. I only take a lane when it would only be for a short distance, and the motorists are aware of me, and **safety depends on it**. If in a bunch, we would take a whole lane *unless it was unsafe*.

The third example sounds more like your case. The other examples show how the local conditions and expectations can change things.

Comment: Some good stuff here andy - but I'm not sure about your third point 'the burbs' - I'd argue that it's always safer to take the lane, to stop opportunistic overtakes where there's not enough room, and because they're more likely to see you if you're in the middle of their sight, than if you're pushed up against the kerb.  You're also less likely to be seen by cars pulling out, more likely to hit a drain, and often have to bob in and out of parked cars.  All in all, better to take the lane.

Comment: @7thGalaxy yes, everyone has to make their own judgement using what they know of local conditions / laws / behavior. My opinion is formed from my experience where I ride. But when you say "more likely to see you", I worry about the time they don't. It only takes once. Your point about drains and parked cars is strong; that's what I mean by "local conditions".

Comment: taking the line it is literally enforced in every bike circulation normative I read.

Answer (score 4):

As @mattnz mentions, it is most likely illegal to split the lane in the manner you describe. While traffic laws differ from place to place, almost any locale with defined lanes will have a law saying that riding/driving between lanes (for longer than it takes to change lanes) is illegal. I strongly advise you to check and follow your local laws. Almost any violation of traffic laws is going to be considered rude.

That said, it often *is* legal to pass on the non-traffic side of the road. That is, pass on the right where people drive on the right and pass on the left where people drive on the left.

When legal, whether or not it is rude depends largely on what happens after you have passed all of these cars. If you're only passing all of this congestion to turn onto a side road and get out of their way, it's probably not a big deal.

If you pass all the congestion and take the lane again (such as you might be able to do at a traffic light or stop sign), then you just passed all of these cars only to slow their progress and force them to pass you again (which creates more congestion) and is certainly rude.

Comment: Actually, some localities apparently allow motorcycles to pass between cars.  It's highly dependent on the rules in your area.

Comment: *If you pass all the congestion and take the lane again ... then you just passed all of these cars only to slow their progress and force them to pass you again ... and is certainly rude.* You've just described a decent proportion of the bike lanes in the UK (where technically you can only enter a bike box on a red light if you do so from the bike lane, which is one reason why it's common to see short stretches leading up to traffic lights.  Also there's a good chance several of those cars were already braking for the lights when they passed you - now whose overtaking is poor?

Comment: If you don't take the lane, and get passed by cars only to be held up by them when it gets congested a few hundred yards further, then the car drivers have gained absolutely nothing, have possibly endangered you by passing too close, and are now holding you up unnecessarily. Avoiding that situation certainly isn't rude, and it is certainly rude of drivers to insist that you put up with that situation.

Comment: @ChrisH If you are using the bike lane, you are *by definition* in a different situation than what the OP is describing. And I certainly don't mean to imply that drivers are never rude or overtake poorly. They do. But that doesn't make it any less rude if we also overtake poorly.

Comment: @armb If a driver passes you only to get held up farther down the road, the driver *has* gained something: he/she has passed you. This is something that the driver would most likely have to do anyway and it doesn't make a difference if they do it before or after hitting congestion. The big difference is that what the OP is describing means that they have to pass you twice. And I'm not saying that you shouldn't take the lane. I'm saying if you do, you're behaving like you're driving a car and you should continue to do so even if you hit congestion.

Comment: If it doesn't make a difference, then they haven't gained anything. And if, as is common in congested stop-start traffic, the average speed of motor traffic is lower than that of cyclists, no they likely wouldn't have to do it anyway.

Comment: @jimirings, yes, you are, but the point is in congested urban traffic bikes pass cars, and cars pass bikes - *on average the bikes are normally quicker*. The onus is always on the overtaker to wait for a safe spot.  The overtakee can help to indicate the presence - or absence - of such a spot. I personally don't go up the inside unless there's a decent width lane for that purpose (passenger doors open in queues) but pass in the middle of the road.  The gap between the lanes, with few exceptions round here, is too narrow for my rather wide handlebars without tilting the bike, foot down.

Comment: @ChrisH I think I see where we're bumping heads. The problem is that the OP hasn't given us enough information. I read the question as asking about short-term, temporary congestion, such as you encounter at major intersections on the edge of the metro area of a major city at rush hour. You seem to have read it as talking about the general congestion in a dense urban area. The OP hasn't actually indicated which type of congestion they're talking about.

Comment: @armb See my comment to ChrisH directly above. (You can only reference one user per comment.)

Comment: Yes. "It depends on local conditions" is the right answer. "It is certainly rude" is, in some conditions, just wrong.

Comment: @armb I think you took that out of context a bit. I gave fairly specific examples of conditions in which it is certainly rude. Anyway, this discussion is getting long, which is discouraged. If you would like, we could carry it on in chat.

Answer (score 3):

"I can safely ride between cars....", You an judge spacing

"a car come up from behind and clip me while overtaking." Car drivers cannot judge spacing.

Is this dichotomy the root of the issue? Your (mine as well) perception is that because you are in control, you are safer than when not in control. Turn this around, and the car driver feels lane splitting is less safe than him passing you. Hence apparent rudeness on your part.

I invite you to explore this as it is the most likley reason you feel its rude.

And to answer the question, it is rude to purposely slow someones progress then pass them, especially if you pass them illegally (Which lane splitting is in many duristrictions), regardless of if its a car, another bike or a runner.

Comment: Yes, I feel that my judgement of spacing is inherently better than a motorists. "Turn this around, and the car driver feels lane splitting is less safe than him passing you. Hence apparent rudeness on your part. " - The rudeness is more that I'm holding traffic up by riding slowly, but not being held up myself.

Comment: I therefore refer you to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illusory_superiority#Driving_ability

Comment: To be fair - surely cyclists genuinely are more aware of their space, how much they're moving about, etc.

Comment: @dwjohnston I don't know about your city, but here, people sometimes jump out of cars at red lights (passenger side), especially kids being brought to school. That's something you typically can't see beforehand and hitting a door (or even worse the kid) is very, very painful.

Comment: @arne - So are you saying don't filter? To be clear - I'm usually cycling _between_ cars - ie. two lanes of traffic. But yes - passenger doors can always open.

Comment: @dwjohnston: I don't filter. Everyone can obviously decide for himself, but I recommend not to or to use extreme care.

Comment: I think that the biggest thing to take into the consideration of what happens when the passing party makes a mistake. If a car clips a cyclist travelling 30 km/h faster than the cyclist, the cyclist could end up dead. If a cyclist passes a car, and hits the car, you might scratch the paint, or at worse, break off the mirror.  The cyclist or his bike would probably be hurt more than the car. The non-offending party (in the car), will have no physical damage.

Comment: Cars are wider and the driver is on the other side of the car relative to the cyclists ... so it's safe to assume that the cyclists is a better judge of spacing the the car driver.

Comment: I see two factors at work. First, most drivers are unaware of how much room a cyclist needs. Second, many drivers simply have no idea how wide their vehicle is, especially as @mtahmed said they are on the other side of the vehicle.

Comment: Yes. A cyclist can see exactly how close his hands are to the side of a car, and can be sure a stationary car won't wobble, and that the breeze of their passing won't disturb the car. A driver passing a cyclist at a higher speed, with much less awareness of how close the outside of their vehicle is to the cyclist, and generally without realizing how a two-wheel vehicle behaves, is much less safe.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on local circumstances. Often, it's the only sane rational way for cyclists to behave. In other places, it's rude because you didn't really need to take the lane for safety. In still other places, it's the rational safe way for a cyclist to behave but will be seen as rude anyway because it violates local expectations.

And some drivers will see it as rude anyway everywhere, because some drivers see the very existence of cyclists on the road as offensive.

Answer (score 1):

I fully support the notion for cyclist to take a lane when no shoulder or bike path is available and there are studies that support it is safer for cyclists and better for the flow of traffic in doing that - https://cyclingsavvy.org/road-cycling/

As for splitting lanes, it boils down to is it legal for bikes/motos to split lanes in your location or not as that is what you are doing. If so, then etiquette does not play into it all that much. The next question then is how safe is splitting lanes? As a motorcycle rider and bicyclist, I think splitting lanes with traffic moving around you is too risky, but when traffic is totally stopped it is less risky. However, the one caveat as a bicyclist is that you have to be careful when splitting lanes + taking the lane especially when traffic gets moving to be able to get back to the right lane. That sometimes is not for the faint of heart.

I would say to touch on etiquette in general don't split lanes if traffic is moving or if you are just coming to a stop light with traffic. There just take your lane and act like a car. If traffic is totally at a stand still, then yes splitting lanes is an option and should not be looked at with too much contempt.

Here is a video of a ride where traffic was stopped for a not so clear reason to me. As a result, I ended up splitting lanes, got caught in the wrong lane when traffic started moving (2:00), and finally got back over to take the right lane. As I think over the several thousand miles I have ridden, this is probably the only time I have ever split lanes, but I have not ridden in places like NYC or LA. Also, note that I am riding slower plus pedaling slower in preparation for a car to move unexpectedly in front of me when splitting lanes.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

I'd say: Stick to it. You take a lane when cars need to wait for you, you take the same lane when you need to wait for cars. Get the message across that yes, you are a vehicle. Yes, you have rights. And yes, you stick to the rules.

---

Personally, I hate the fact that everytime that I talk to a car driver, the very first reaction is: "You guys don't stick to the rules, and you have the cheek to claim rights?!?" Would you want to start a discussion about when it is legal to overtake a bike and when not after such an introduction? **We are hurting our cause with our own behavior**.

You see, the problem with bikes in traffic is the way we are seen. Car drivers don't see vehicles, they see people who give a **** for the rules, who don't seem to need safety distances as they pass through the safety distances between real vehicles, etc. **If we don't stick to the rules when they are inconvenient to us, we cannot demand that the car drivers stick to the rules when they are inconvenient to them**. Safety distances work both ways, we need to respect them as well. Teach your local car drivers that you stick to the rules, and that you demand that they stick to the rules as well. Respect all red lights. Take your lane when appropriate, not when convenient. Yield to cars when they have the right of way. Don't ride on sidewalks unless prescribed by law. Keep your safety distances to all other vehicles at all times. If all bikers would do that, roads would be a much safer place for us very quickly.